# mysql arethmitic operation of fields

Tags: php, mysql, twitter

i need a mysql command to select users where last tweeting time greater than or equal (the current time minus number of tweets )

```
$sel_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `last_update`>=(".time()." - `num_tweet`)");
```

where:

`num_tweet` is a number of tweets like tweet every hour -> 3600 , tweet every 2 hours -> 7200

the complete code:

```
$now = time();
$sel_users = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `status`='1' AND `last_update`<=($now - `num_tweet`)");
$num = @mysql_num_rows($sel_users);
//echo $num;
if($num > 0){
  while($row_users = mysql_fetch_array($sel_users)){
    $sel_tweet = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `tweets_library` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0,1");
    if(@mysql_num_rows($sel_tweet) > 0){
      $row_tweet    = @mysql_fetch_array($sel_tweet);
      $twitteroauth = new TwitterOAuth($YOUR_CONSUMER_KEY, $YOUR_CONSUMER_SECRET, $row_users['access_token_oauth_token'], $row_users['access_token_oauth_token_secret']);
      $tweet = $twitteroauth->post('statuses/update',array('status' => $row_tweet['msg']));
      if($tweet->id){$now = time();mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `last_update`='$now' WHERE `id`='$row_users[id]'");}
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't generate times in PHP and stuff them into the query. MySQL can do that for you: `WHERE last_update >= (unix_timestamp(now()) - num_tweet)`. Plus, any reason why your single line sample uses `>=` and your full sample uses `<=`?

Comment: yes, i mean <= in sample sorry